# How to comment code in Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, erb, erubis

As I'm playing with Rails and developing views I often want to comment out code. Simple enough with classes & models but **views** are a bit more tricky.

What's best way to comment code in a view so it's not interpreted by, well, anything... HTML gives us `<!-- commented Rails code here -->` though code enclosed here seems to get interpreted anyway?!? Or is there a more Railsy way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`<% code code # comment %>` USED to work but I think that was accidental.

You were always supposed to put comments in separate comment tags `<%# comment %>`

Note NO SPACE before the pound.

Now the old loophole is closed (I forget whether 'now' means Ruby 1.8 or Rails 3 or what) so that:

```
<% code code  #  this runs too %>
<% # also runs %>
<%# the only way to comment out %>
```

Answer (score 8):

I use this all the time

```
<%# This is a comment %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason Ruby code would be executed inside `<!-- -->` HTML comments is because all of the server side code (ie. Ruby) is interpreted *first*, and then the output is sent to the client, at which point the browser interprets `<!-- -->` as a comment. As the other answers said, use `<% #comment %>` to comment within a Rails view.

Comment: HAML equavilent: `-# comment`

Answer (score 2):

Although (and i'm hoping to be corrected here) you have to be careful because i've had some really strange behavior when doing something like this:

```
<% if (my_boolean) # Commenting on this if-block %>
```

where it will affect the HTML that directly follows that (even if it's on another line).

Anyone?

And would this qualify as an answer, or a comment?

Answer (score 1):

```
<% #comment here %>
```

:D